# Exponentially-distributed lifetimes (death process)

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In a pure death process where the individual death rate is fixed at v, because the process is a time-homogeneous Markov process, the wating time till the next "event" (i.e. the wating time till the individual's death, i.e. the remaining lifetime of the individual) is exponentially distributed. By the memorylessness of the exponential distribution, the lifetime of the individual is also exponentially distributed with the same parameter v.

This means that if the individual has lived 20 yrs, the probability that they are going to live 30 more years is the same as the probability of having a lifespan of 30 years. And that the expected lifetime of the individual is the same as the expected remaining lifetime.

Something seems amiss with my argument above. Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, you are rediscovering the so-called memoryless property of the exponential distribution. This is the fact that if $X$ is exponentially distributed, then, for every nonnegative $t$ and $s$, $P[X\geqslant t+s\mid X\geqslant s]=P[X\geqslant t]$ (and this probability is $\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}$, where $\lambda$ is the parameter of the exponential distribution).

Comment: Thanks- good to know that I have not misunderstood the memorylessness of the exponential distribution. But it seems totally counterintuitive that my expected lifespan as a newborn is exactly the same as my expected remaining lifetime as a 70yo person. In the former, I expect to live up to (say) 80yo, and in the latter I correspondingly expect to live up to 150yo (and the probability of each is the same)?? Is there a flaw in my understanding, or is this anomaly a consequence of the fact that the pure death process is a completely inappropriate model for human lifetimes?

Comment: Humans are expected to *age*--which means in particular that, at least after a while, the *rate* at which they die increases. Exponential lifetime = constant death rate.

Comment: I like how you spell it out. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.